# return a pointer struct from a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to return the user input of which row and column to 'switch' (it's supposed to be a game called Teaser), but I'm not sure how to return the value that I want to.

The warning I'm getting is:

> ```
> warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion
>   returning 'move *' from a function with result type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
> ```

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int column;
} move;

 /* Function:    getNextMove
 * Description: Ask the user for a new move or if the user want to quit
 *              the game.
 * Input:       A pointer to a move structure. Coordinates for the next move
 *              or a signal from the user to end the game.
 * Output:      Return 0 if the user want to end the game, 1 otherwise.
 *              Return the coordinates for the next game through the
 *              structure pointed to.
 */

int getNextMove(move *nextMove) {

    printf("Make a move (Row = 0 ends the game)\n");
    printf("Row = ");
    scanf("%d", &nextMove->row);
    if (nextMove->row == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Column = ");
    scanf("%d", &nextMove->column);

    return nextMove;
}
```

Comment: `int getNextMove(move *nextMove) {`  --> `move *getNextMove(move *nextMove) {`  also `return 0;` --> `return NULL;`

Comment: Well, you have a function with a return type of `int` and you're returning a `move*` from it. That's not going to work.

Comment: The return type of a function is not a guideline, it's a rule. If your function has a return type `int`, then that's what it should return. have it return a `move *`, or `int` , and change the calling code accordingly

Comment: The choice of words used in the function documentation is unfortunate, and contributes to confusion.  It is more common to describe at least three categories: `input:..., output:,... and return:...`   With `output` in your code being described as `struct move *`, and `return` being described as `1 for success, 0 for failure`, (or whatever your preference is)

Comment: Besides it's actually pointless to return `nextMove` with your implementation, because after invoking `move *move1 = getNextMove(move2)`, `move1` will be the same as `move2`. In your case `return nextMove;` should be simply replaced by `return 1;`. And you should invoke getnextMove like this `int continuegame = getNextMove(mynextmove)`.

Comment: @ryyker Maybe it is yes, I got the file with the comments already in place, and empty functions. But I'm quite new and I like the challenge, even though I sometimes mess up on simple things..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't return more than one value as suggested by the function banner comment. Return the 0 or 1 to indicate game status and the value stored in the address pointed to by nextMove is changed by the scanf() function calls:

```
int getNextMove(move *nextMove) {
    printf("Make a move (Row = 0 ends the game)\n");
    printf("Row = ");
    scanf("%d", &nextMove->row);
    if (nextMove->row == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Column = ");
    scanf("%d", &nextMove->column);

    return 1;
}
```

For the record if you did want to return a pointer to a move struct an example could be:

```
move * getMove(void)
{
    static move moveToReturn;

    /* some operations on the move stucture */

    return &moveToReturn
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that "return the coordinates for the next move" was "automatically done" via the scanf. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 4):

You made a simple error. The function's documentation says:

```
Output:      Return 0 if the user want to end the game, 1 otherwise.
```

But, instead, you're returning `0` or the value of `nextMove`.

`nextMove` is a `move*`, not an `int`, hence the warning. This is also why warnings are so helpful, because they have pointed out this mistake that you have made in returning the wrong thing.

Change `return nextMove` to `return 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are (sometimes) returning the argument.  What's the point of that?  There's no need to return anything in that case.

If you did want to return a pointer to a `move`, though, then your function should declare that as its return type:

```
move * getNextMove(move * nextMove) {
    ...
    return nextMove;
}
```

Comment: Note, too, that returning the `move *` is contrary to the documentation of the function.